# Vanishing self-intersection of a divisor on surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $D$ be a non-zero effective divisor on a smooth projective surface $S$ (over complex numbers). Let the self-intersection number of $D$ i.e $D^2=0$. In this context my questions are the following :

$(1)$  what does this geometrically signify? Is there any interesting property of $D$ in this situation?

$(2)$ What can we say if for a nonzero effective divisor$D$ on a surface, if its volume is $\text{Vol}_S(D)=0$?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Hi, for (1) the self-intersection in this context can be computed by intersecting $D$ with an infinitesimal transverse deformation of $D$. The number you get in the end should be thought of as the multiplicity of the generic point of $D$. Hence $D^2 = 0$ means that $D$ does not have a generic point.
This is informal and one can probably say a lot more but I'm a beginner in intersection theory! :)

Comment: @Thrgl where did you get the description of $D^2$ as computing the multiplicity of the generic point? That suggests that it somehow measures how singular $D$ is, which is absolutely not the case; you can get the full range of intersection numbers just from smooth curves on surfaces.

Comment: @TabesBridges that's what I read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory#Intersection_multiplicities): "the self-intersection point of $C$ is the generic point of $C$ with multiplicity $C\cdot C$".
But the usual interpretation I know of is the one which you developped in your answer. 

Moreover my first comment was wrong, it should read "if $D^2=0$ then the multiplitcity of the generic point is $0$". Probably this makes more sense?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now; I had not encountered the notion of the ``self-intersection point" before. However $D^2=0$ does not mean that $D$ lacks a generic point, but that the "generic deformation" has no fixed points, which indeed means that this peculiar intersection scheme is empty hence has multiplicity $0$.

Answer (score 2):

As the first comment says, we can compute $D^2$ in many cases by intersecting with an infinitesimal transverse deformation; in other words, $D^2$ is the degree of the normal bundle to $D$ in $S$, or the number of fixed points of a generic deformation of $D$. This can also typically be computed using an honest deformation if $D^2 \ge 0$. If $D^2 < 0$, that means that $D$ is rigid, i.e. it cannot be deformed in $S$.

As for the volume: does this always coincide with $D^2$ for surfaces? I don't recall off hand. Perhaps THE example of a divisor with zero self-intersection is the fiber class of a morphism to a curve, i.e. for any distinct $x,y\in S$, $f^{-1}(x)$ and $f^{-1}(y)$ are disjoint. So in this case, the vanishing of the volume is telling you that the image of the morphism associated to the fiber class has smaller dimension than $S$ itself.

Comment: thanks. can we say anything specific about emptiness or nonemptiness of the linear system $|K_S-D|$ in both the situations? Here $K_S$ stands for the canonical bundle of the surface.

Comment: @HARRY If, for example, $S$ is a rational surface, $K_S$ has no sections (since 1. $K_{\mathbb P^2}$ does not, and 2. the integers $h^0(mK_S)$ are birational invariants), so subtracting anything effective will leave the linear system empty. The same argument works if $\kappa(S)=0$ (i.e. $S$ is abelian, K3, Enriques, or bielliptic). For surfaces of positive Kodaira dimension, the only thing I can tell you is to pick an ample class $H$ and compute $H.(K_S-D)$. If this is positive, then you might have sections. But I have a feeling quite a few different things can happen.